# How to make an array of Cards Also how to match them easily

Tags: java, arrays, java-collections-api

I am making a crazy eights java card game and made an array of cards for one players hand, but when I try to print out that hand its a jumble of random characters. I also have a card class but that seems to be fine. Please help.

**Error:**

```
Welcome to Crazy Eights!(Type 0 to start)
0
Your Hand:
[LnnajiO.Card;@73ae74f5
```

**Card Class:**

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Card {

//All of the card numbers, in strings
final String[] FACESTRINGS = {"" , "Ace" , "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", 
        "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
//All of the card numbers as integers
final int[] FACENUMS = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
final String[] SUITSTRINGS = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
final int[] SUITNUMS = {1,2,3,4};

int FaceNumIndex;
int SuitIndex;
int cardFaceNumber;
String cardFaceString;
int suitFaceNumber;
String suitFaceString;
Random rand = new Random();

    //Default Random Card that assignes a random suit and number
public Card(){
    int tempSuit = rand.nextInt(3);
    int tempNumber = rand.nextInt(13)+1;
    FaceNumIndex = tempNumber;
    cardFaceNumber = FACENUMS[tempNumber];
    cardFaceString = FACESTRINGS[tempNumber];
    suitFaceNumber = SUITNUMS[tempSuit];
    suitFaceString = SUITSTRINGS[tempSuit];

}

    //Overrides the default 
public Card(int suit, int face){
    //Return 1-13 for the face and 0-3 for the suit
    FaceNumIndex = face;
    SuitIndex = suit;
    cardFaceNumber = FACENUMS[face];
    cardFaceString = FACESTRINGS[face];
    suitFaceNumber = SUITNUMS[suit];
    suitFaceString = SUITSTRINGS[suit];
}

public void setFaceName(int faceName){
    //Takes an int to set the Suit of the card  input 1-13
    FaceNumIndex = faceName;
    cardFaceNumber = FACENUMS[faceName];
    cardFaceString = FACESTRINGS[faceName];
}

public void setSuitName(int suitName){
    //Takes an int 1-4 to set the suit name from the array
    SuitIndex = suitName;
    suitFaceNumber = SUITNUMS[suitName];
    suitFaceString = SUITSTRINGS[suitName];
}
//Returns Face Values
public int getFace(){
    return FACENUMS[FaceNumIndex];
}
public String getFaceName(){
    return FACESTRINGS[FaceNumIndex];
}

//Return Suit Values
public int getSuit(){
    return SUITNUMS[SuitIndex];
}
public String getSuitName(){
    return SUITSTRINGS[SuitIndex];
}

//Compares this card to the returned class
public boolean isHigherThan(Card passCard, boolean AceHigher){
    int tempCardSuit = passCard.getSuit();
    int tempCardFace = passCard.getFace();
    if (tempCardFace>FaceNumIndex){
        return false;
    }else if (tempCardFace<FaceNumIndex){
        return true;
    }else{
        if (tempCardSuit>SuitIndex){
            return false;
        }else if(tempCardSuit<SuitIndex){
            return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("The Cards are equal");
            return false;
        }
    }

}

//Override for previous isHigherThan
public boolean isHigherThan(Card PassCard){

    return isHigherThan(PassCard, true);

}

public String toString(){
    return cardFaceString + " of " + suitFaceString;
}

public boolean isHigherThan(int i, String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Also for this "if" statement I was to make it so that it will check if any of the "suitFaceNumber" or "cardFaceNumber" of any of the cards in player2's hand match the "suitFaceNumber" or "cardFaceNumber" of the starting card, instead of doing it one by one.

**"if" statement**

```
if(player2Hand[0].cardFaceNumber==startingCard.cardFaceNumber ||
   player2Hand[4].suitFaceNumber==startingCard.suitFaceNumber ){

}
```

Comment: You are printing the MEMORY LOCATION of your object card. You have to call toString() when trying to show it. (As I saw you overrided the toString so its nice)

Comment: why not enclosing your "if" logic under a for loop to traverse all cards in the hand ?

Comment: @dan Rank and suit of playing cards are prime candidates for enum types.

Comment: I don't understand why the condition in the "if" statement uses 0 and 4 - presumably it should be the same value, an index as Solano suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Your method

```
public String toString(){...}
```

in class Card prints a single card, but when you have a

```
Card[] hand
```

this isn't automatically applied to the array elements. You'll have to write a method iterating over the array.

Alternatively, write a class Hand, which would then have a toString of its own.

Comment: he already did it. maybe he is not calling toString in the print method